# How can i get all window's elements with values in Xorg?

Tags: java, linux, window, element, xorg

I want to get external window's elements like labels, inputs, textareas with values in linux by "Window id" using java.
Is it possible with Xorg?

Comment: Whats wrong with using `Swing`? It will work on all operating systems that have Java installed.

Comment: i want to do something like this: run java program, choice the window (like skype) and get elements of this window.

Comment: it's generally not possible (or very much toolkit dependent). X11 protocol is low level and know nothing about intended behavior / api of any widget.

Comment: Does exist another way to get windows elements data?